# syntax error in angular mock service

Tags: angular, mocking

I have an original service (in angular 5)  with API that returns Observable.

I need to create similar mock service called ServiceStub.
In the mock I provide this API definition (same signature as original) but reading from a local json file:

```
    public myAPI(): Observable<CompleObject[]> {

            const x = this.httpClient.get('..//stubs/myJsonFile.json');
            return Observable.of(x) // syntax error here
        }
```

so in the module where the original service is provided, I replace this line:

```
OriginalService
```

(in the providers array) by

```
{ provide: OriginalService, useClass: ServiceStub },
```

Running the app, with a small modification to myAPI() in the mock just to get it to build, I get that the original is still called instead of the mock. Despite of the previously mentioned changed to the module, where I instruct the mock to be used in all places where the original was intended.

Answer (score 1):

Is `httpClient` the actual `HttpClient` from `HttpClientModule`? If so, I think you could just return `x` rather than `of(x)` since `get()` already returns an `Observable`.

Comment: Thanks Frank, now it doesn't work because x is an Observable<Object> whereas the method return type is Observable<MyCustomComplexObject[]>. A mapping must be missing?
And httpClient is of type HttpClient from '@angular/common/http';

Comment: Ah, it sounds like an issue I ran into the other day actually. Try calling `get` by declaring the type e.g. `get<CompleObject[]>('path/to/doc')`.

Comment: Thank you Frank I hadn't realised you posted this. It didn't work for me with get, maybe we re working with diff versions of angular or I didn't import it from the correct namespace (several suggestions had popped up) so I in the end I used require and posted that solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in teh definition of the API from the mock:

```
const x = <MyComplexObject[]> (require('..//stubs/myJSONFile.json'));
return Observable.of(x);
```

Now it works.